# Rows of string to List set

Tags: python, list, wxpython

I have a mental block on List formats.
Any help would be appreciative.

I have my edited ListCtrol to print:

```
2, 200, 487
1, 199, 486
```

I need to reload these rows of string to a list set like:

```
[['2', '200', '487'], ['1', '199', '486']]
```

or to:

```
{1: ["2", "200", "487"],
                2: ["1", "199", "486"]
                }
```

Here is my statement I want to format to list.  I think I need to re-write this using a for loop.

```
line = str(", ".join([self.lc.GetItem(row, col).GetText() for col in range(self.lc.GetColumnCount())]))
```

Comment: Can you post your code so we can see what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
s = """2, 200, 487
1, 199, 486"""
print [line.split() for line in s.splitlines()]
```

Comment: Thats partly what I need.  My output is a file type or something that print only the last row.

Comment: what? can you rephrase that? I dont understand

Comment: In python your suggestion works fine, just change to str.  However I'm using wxpython ListCtrl.  I only get the last row in your code.  I'm think I need a comprehensive list format that uses for loop.

Comment: there thats what you want?

Comment: Thank you Joran.  Sometimes the questions are harder than the answer.